# Какого рода слово "маршмеллоу"?

Tags: морфология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какого рода (а заодно и числа) слово "маршмеллоу" (он же — жевательный зефир)?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А почему его по-русски не называть? Вот интуитивно это слово м.р., причем ед. ч. Во мн. ч его как-то не получается перевести. Либо уж сразу писать латиницей - как в оригинале, marshmallow. По крайней мере склонять не придется =)

Comment: Потому что это не конфеты и не зефир. А то, по Вашей логике, "шоколад" тоже надо писать латиницей или называть конфетами (равно, как, кстати, и сами конфеты) ))))) Маршмеллоу — это совершенно самостоятельный вид сладостей. "Жевательным зефиром" его называют условно, но готовится он совершенно по-другому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
м.род
маршмеллоу (Именительный падеж единственного числа)
```

маршмеллоу (Родительный падеж единственного числа)

маршмеллоу (Дательный падеж единственного числа)

маршмеллоу (Винительный падеж единственного числа)

маршмеллоу (Творительный падеж единственного числа)

маршмеллоу (Предложный падеж единственного числа)

маршмеллоу (Именительный падеж множественного числа)

маршмеллоу (Родительный падеж множественного числа)

маршмеллоу (Дательный падеж множественного числа)

маршмеллоу (Винительный падеж множественного числа)

маршмеллоу (Творительный падеж множественного числа)

маршмеллоу (Предложный падеж множественного числа).Нашел в интернете

Comment: Не поделитесь источником. По гуглу, "вкусный мармешллоу" 5 упоминаний,   а "вкусное мармешллоу" - 37, к тому же есть слова с идентичной концовкой среднего рода. Откуда мужской род?

Comment: Конечно,поделюсь. http://www.multitran.ru/c/M.exe?a=118&t=109936_2_4

Comment: @Марк Из, а почему тогда не женского рода, если это аналог пастилы?

Comment: @gecube, потому что:

1. Рецептуры пастилы и маршмеллоу имеют существенные различия.  
2. Есть идентично заканчивающиеся слова, именно среднего рода (шоу).  
3. Несклоняемые существительные в русском языке, если не принадлежат лицу одушевлённому,  как правило имеют средний род. Даже если образованы от слов другого рода (ср. *авто от автомобиль, метро от метрополитен*).  
4. Частотность употребления слова в среднем роде существенно выше, чем в мужском.

Comment: Это НИ РАЗУ не аналог пастилы. Как я писала выше, это совершенно самостоятельный вид сладостей, похожий на пастилу или зефир только внешне, да и то отдаленно.

Answer (score 1):

Слово в словарях не зафиксировано. На практике употребляется в среднем роде (ср. *шоу, соло*).